# Get element types from typing.Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that takes a type and recursively generates an element of that type. For example, for `typing.NamedTuple`s I do this:

```
def make_type(type_):
  ...
  if issubclass(type_, typing.NamedTuple):
    return type_(**{f: make_type(t) for f, t in type_._field_types.items()})
```

However, I'm not sure how to handle `typing.Tuple`s, as they don't seem to have an equivalent of `_field_types`. For example, if I had a `Tuple[int, int]` I would like to get back `(int, int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I can just use the `__args__` field of my type:

```
Pair = typing.Tuple[int, int]
Pair.__args__ # (int, int)
```

I assume that this is just the argument list passed into the `Tuple` type constructor. Feels a bit undocumented, but oh well.